# Dual Interface smart card reader switching

Tags: smartcard, contactless-smartcard, winscard

I am using HID omnikey 5421 smart card reader. reader is dual interface, when i was reading dual interface (contact and contactless) card it's automtically read contactless data in sometime, contact data in sometime.but i want to read contact card data first.after reading contact card details remove dual interface card then i put another contactless card, to read data from contactless (this card contactless only). this scenario how to handle. i was checked options in HID omnikey reader.

please give suggestion to me.

Comment: can you please clear the question?

Comment: @vikky I have one dual interface reader(contact + contactless) when plug dual interface card contactless automatically detected how to i prevent this case.

Comment: use SCardConnect function and pass the reader name(either contact or contactless)

Comment: I tried to manually select reader and to connect, that also same.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @vikky this is third party dll file invoke for read dual interface card.

Comment: download HID Omnikey Workbench from https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/14993 and change the reader setting(turn off the antenna)

Comment: @vikky thanks!,yes your correct, first i read contact card after that read contactless card that is difficult...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89902/discussion-between-vikky-and-senthilkumar).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of selecting a reader programmatically. It is from a code example in Java of how to use the PC/SC drivers - worth reading if you are getting started with smart cards: http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com.es/2010/06/pcsc-sample-in-java.html

As you can see in this code block, it reads the list of terminals - then selects the first one. In your reader, you will probably get two: contact and contactless. Just `get`the one you want to use and you are done!

```
   // Display the list of terminals
   TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
   List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
   System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

   // Use the first terminal
   CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
```

Ludovic Rousseau's site has examples using several more programming languages. As I said, a very good resource!

Comment: sorry i forget to say! I am using some third party dll for read contact and contactless card. that is not common card isolated

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any C# code. Maybe there is something in the website I linked above.
If you are using a 3rd party DLL, then the solution will totally depend on it. The code linked above is general-purpose, sometimes it is better to have that kind of control...

Answer (score 1):

Where you are experiencing this issue, you need to disable the contactless interface temporarily. You need to download the HID Omnikey Workbench software. http://www.hidglobal.com/sites/hidglobal.com/files/resource_files/omnikey_contactless_developer_guide.pdf[image]

Comment: yes, your are correct, but at the same time we need to read contactless card also that is our issue.

Comment: I think you have just three options. First, contact HID Global, and ask them how to perform the low-level antenna disable. Second, work the antenna disable into your manual process. Or thirdly - and probably most practical - use a separate reader - i.e. either use the Omnikey for contactless only, and another reader for contact - or disable the Omnikey antenna, and use another contactless reader.